# using doctrine's dbal in symfony2 with forms

Tags: php, symfony

So I want to do the following:

I created a form class at /Form/Type/UserType.php

I have a table with a list of states (table named "states").

I want to show all of these states in a drop down menu.

What code should I use in the class UserType to show all the states?

I tried:

```
    $request = new Request;
    $conn = $request->get('database_connection');
    $states = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT state_code, state_name FROM states');

    $builder->add('state', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => $states,
        'required'  => false,
   ));
```

but that gives me an error. Basically, I want to query all of the states from the table states, and create a drop down menu from all of these states.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `State` entity, map it to `states` table and create a `OneToMany` relation with the `User` entity. Then in your `UserType` form `$builder->add('state')` should create dropdown field automatically. You also have to set `data_class` option to your `User` entity in `getDefaultOptions` method of `UserType` form.

Answer (score 0):

@m2mdas has given you the correct object based answer.  However, if all you really want to do is to store the state_code then what you have will almost work.  You just need to get the connection right.

```
class MyType extends extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct($em) { $this->em = $em; }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $conn = $this->em->getConnection();
        $statesx = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT state_code, state_name FROM states');

        // Need to index for the choice
        $states = array();
        foreach($statesx as $state) 
        { 
            $states[$state['state_code']] = $state['state_name']; 
        }

        $builder->add('state', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => $states,
            'required'  => false,
        ));

...
// In your controller
$form = new MyType($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager());
```